# Instrument(s) for measuring (and recording) temperature, voltage and current

Tags: arduino, multimeter, thermocouple

I'm about to embark on a series of experiments regarding thermoelectricity. I am pretty new to instrumentation etc - though I played with electronics as a hobby, when I was a boy.

I am starting to acquire a set of tools for this exercise.

Which device(s) can I use (multimeter perhaps?) to measures:

- Temperature (up to say 700 degrees Celsius)
- Voltage (from a few millivolts to a few volts)
- Current (from a few milliamps to a few amps)

Last but not the least, I would like to record the generated data (voltage, current and temperature) using an arduino Uno.

Can anyone suggest a circuit I can use to capture and record the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a digital multimeter (DMM) with a thermocouple setting. And a thermocouple sensor that works with it.

If you're spending enough to get the thermocouple function, you can likely get a DMM that does its own recording at no additional charge, so no Arduino or other device would be needed to achieve that function.

If you want to avoid spending a few hundred dollars on a known-accurate DMM, you can investigate making your own *cold junction* circuit to allow reading the thermocouple with any voltage meter (or the ADC function that's probably included in your Arduino) you like.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can tell that you're very knowledgeable about the subject matter at hand - because I (as a mere novice), barely understood what you wrote. May I be so bold as to ask you to please explain (*ELIF*) what you mean by the following: _investigate making your own cold junction circuit to allow reading the thermocouple with any voltage meter (or the ADC function that's probably included in your Arduino)_ Thanks

Comment: Also, I've see [this digital multi meter](http://www.toolstation.com/shop/p21374?mkwid=s22l43ki0_dc&pcrid=142002554548&pkw=&pmt=&product=21374&gclid=CjwKEAjw5M3GBRCTvpK4osqj4X4SJAAB)  - what's your opinion on it's suitability to the task at hand? - I know it's at the low end - but my wife will kill me if I spend too much (initially anyway) on my hobby - until I can actually justify what I'm doing ;)

Comment: I mean google the term "cold junction circuit" and read the information you find. That multimeter looks okay given the price, and does seem to have some kind of thermocouple. There are different types, suitable for different temperature ranges, and you'd need to read the meter's manual (or find a more detailed datahseet for it) to find out which type it is designed to work with.

Comment: FYI the main risks with a cheap meter are 1. It won't be super accurate (could be a few % error, probably not critical for most hobbyist projects). 2. Might not really be safe for high voltages --- don't use it to debug your mains circuits.